# sql query with left join condition

Tags: sql, postgresql

Below is a SQL query:

```
SELECT ID, NAME FROM TABLE1 A
LEFT JOIN TABLE2 B
ON A.COLUMN1=B.COLUMN1
WHERE (
A.NAME = 'TEST'
OR
(NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM TABLE3 C 
WHERE C.COLUMN1=A.COLUMN2
AND C.COLUMN2=B.COLUMN2)
AND 
NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM TABLE4 D 
WHERE D.COLUMN1=A.COLUMN2
AND D.COLUMN2=B.COLUMN2)));
```

which does not seem to be supported currently, would there be a different approach for this?

Alternative that I have already tried, but gives different result:

```
A.COLUMN2 NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT COLUMN1 FROM TABLE3)
```

Comment: Actually, this _should_ be supported by Redshift AFAIK.  What is the actual error message?

Comment: That query is most certainly supported by Postgres - which DBMS are you really using? `select version()` will tell you. And what is the error message you get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try refactoring to use left anti-joins instead of the exists subqueries:

```sql
SELECT ID, NAME
FROM TABLE1 A
LEFT JOIN TABLE2 B
    ON A.COLUMN1 = B.COLUMN1
LEFT JOIN TABLE3 C
    ON C.COLUMN1 = A.COLUMN2 AND
       C.COLUMN2 = B.COLUMN2
LEFT JOIN TABLE4 D 
    ON D.COLUMN1 = A.COLUMN2 AND
       D.COLUMN2 = B.COLUMN2
WHERE
    A.NAME = 'TEST' AND
    C.COLUMN1 IS NULL AND
    D.COLUMN1 IS NULL;
```

Comment: Tim Biegeleisen is correct you need to rewrite this query.  There are 2 reasons for this.  1) It's a correlated sub-query and this isn't support by Redshift and even if this wasn't the case 2) WHERE NOT EXIST statements can be extremely inefficient on a clustered database.